# Eclipse JAR export not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I've just started learning Java (about a week ago) and the last few days I've build a little game using Slick2D. Anyway, whenever I export a JAR from eclipse and run it with 'java blahblahblah.jar' I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/andy/Desktop/game/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Users.andy.Desktop.game.jar
```

Everything is ticked to be exported, the LWJGL and Slick2D jars are in the lib folder and I've tried FatJar. I've looked on the internet and I can't seem to find any solution that works.

Any help?

Comment: What's the exact command you're using?

Comment: java /Users/andy/Desktop/game.jar

Comment: Baring in mind I've also tried -jar and I get:

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
/Users/andy/Desktop/game.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Anyway, whenever I export a JAR from eclipse and run it with 'java blahblahblah.jar' I get the [an error]

You need to use:

```
java -jar blahblahblah.jar
```

**Edit:**
Based on a comment to your original post, it seems like you are exporting the jar without a manifest. Make sure you choose `Runnable Jar` from the export menu. Also be sure to select a valid `Run Configuration` for your game while exporting.

Comment: His comment says he already has, but the manifest is not setup

Comment: That returns:

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from /Users/andy/Desktop/game.jar

Comment: Thanks. That solved it :) Although now I have a seperate problem 'no lwjgl in java.library.path' but I'll look around to solve that. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
java -cp your_jar.jar package.name.ClassName
```

where ClassName is the class with main defined.

The -cp switch means classpath, which specifies the places that java will use to find classes.

After this, is the name of the class to use as an entry point.  If you wanted to supply arguments to it (to the main method) then they would go after the class name.

If you need to specify multiple jar files in the class path, separate them with a colon on linux or a semi colon in windows

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. The package is as follows:

    package slick.path2glory.SimpleGame;

Yet this is the response:

    java -cp ~/desktop/game.jar     slick.path2glory.SimpleGame.SimpleGame
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/newdawn/slick/BasicGame

Comment: So it's finding your class now, but not this other one.  Where is that class defined?  In a separate jar file you imported in eclipse?

Comment: Because you need to include the Slick2D and LWJGL jars on your classpath.  `java -cp your_jar.jar:Slick2d.jar:LWJGL.jar package.name.ClassName`